# PM2 - Run Coffeescript file with NodeJS Parameters

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, pm2

I have a NodeJS app written in coffeescript that requires me to set the stack_size parameter in order for it to run correctly. The command looks like this to get it running.

```
coffee --nodejs --stack_size=65000 app.coffee
```

Now I'd like to integrate this in to PM2, but can't figure out how to add a parameter like stack_size. How would I go about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There you go:

```
pm2 start app.coffee --node-args="--max-stack-size=65000"
```

[Documentation](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/#42-ways-of-starting-processes)

Note that since pm2@2.x you have to first install the coffee support:

```
pm2 install coffeescript
```